# One vs All appraoch to multiclassification in LIBSVM

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I'm working on multiclass classification problem (precisely 4 classes). I want to use the most simple approach for this problem: one-vs-all! I have 4 different test set (only labels are different). Using one-vs-all approach, during test, for each input pattern, I have to compute 4 different objective function values from 4 different SMVs. So, the pattern will belong to the class with the greatest objective function value.

So, I tried this:

./svm-train -s 0 -t 5 -c 16 -g 0.05 -b 1 'traindata'

./svm-predict -b 1 'testdata' 'traindata.model' 'outfile'

I'm not sure about the means of **b parameter**. Opening the file 'outfile' generated from svm-predict, I get probabilistic values. I suppose that comparing these probabilistic values between all SVMs, I'm able to classify each pattern in the class with the greatest probabilistic value. My assumption is correct? In other words, I want to be sure that these probabilistic values are directly proportional to the relative objective function values.

Answer (score 1):

well the ''-b'' 1 option that you have used on prediction gives you the probability of prediction (measure of confidence) . for 1 vs all classification you can use this link:
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f808

Answer (score 0):

As Shirin Feiz says the "-b 1" options gives you a probability estimate. It worth to mention that it applies a sigmoid function to the raw score in order to get a value in [0 1]. The parameters of the sigmoid are learned on each training data.